# Sleep.bat Shortcut File Permanently Made My Computer Sleep Every Time When Idle After 20 Minutes. How To Fix?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep

I created a shortcut batch file to put my computer to sleep:

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

Now my computer goes to sleep after like 20 minutes of being idle.  When I wake it up, I see a command prompt briefly that says something like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

How do I revert back to the way it was previously.  I deleted the batch file, but it still goes to sleep all the time.  Please help.

The Event Log Follows:

```
The system is entering sleep.

Sleep Reason: Application API

Event ID: 42

Task Category: (64)

Keywords: (4)

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
  <EventID>42</EventID> 
  <Version>2</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>64</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000004</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-06T08:58:18.263048300Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>343292</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="88" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Name-PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="TargetState">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="EffectiveState">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="Reason">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="Flags">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

The command or it's files have nothing to do with your problem.

Go to 'power options' and make the correct settings there.

Comment: I have.  It doesn't make any difference at all.  Even changed the advanced options.